# rewrite different url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to med_rewrite and so far I've had no luck pointing one specific address to another. What I want to do is point (301 redirect)

http://roskilde-open.dk/?p=708
to
http://canopysound.dk/index.php/blog/festivalanlaeg-batteri/

I don't want to make any general rule, since it is only this specific page that I need to redirect.

This has been quite a headache so far :(

Best regards
Viktor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*p=708.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^roskilde-open.dk$
RewriteRule .*  http://canopysound.dk/index.php/blog/festivalanlaeg-batteri? [L, R=301]
```

**UPDATED**

I updated to make sure only the query `p=708` triggers the redirection.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick :) Is this a 301 redirect?

Comment: The answer is updated. If you are satisfied with the answer, you might consider [**accepting**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it.

Comment: For some reason it gives me 500 internal server error, when I put R=301 in. Before it worked perfect :/

Comment: There is no reason for that error. Please check there is no garbage in the .htacces file and also try copying and pasting to make sure there are no typos. You can try the rules [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: The .htaccess in my root directory is all empty. And I copy pasted the code above too. Any other suggestions? btw. I accepted the answer, since this specific issue is something to do with my setup

Comment: I agree. There must be something in the setup that has to be modified and it might be in `httpd.conf`. Meanwhile, remove the R=302. It won't redirect permanent but for your application I guess it won't do much difference.

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to damage pagerank, and from what I know google is pretty strict about redirecting.

Comment: I don't know their policies on that matter, but I guess they apply also to permanent redirections. I think the problem in this case is the redirection is originated in a query and that's the reason why can't be permanent. Makes sense, but I am not sure. I am just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution (without any regex, wildcards or something like that):

```
RedirectPermanent <olduri> <newuri>
```

In your case:

```
RedirectPermanent /?p=708 http://canopysound.dk/index.php/blog/festivalanlaeg-batteri/
```

"Permanent" automatically returns an 301 (Moved Per­man­ently).

(Note: newuri has to be a full uri including domain name)
Take a look at: http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/301-redirect.htm